# systemd service everything read-only except 1 folder

Tags: systemd

I'm going to run a script I don't trust for not messing up my system.

I want to start a shell for which everything is read-only except the folder in my home directory which the script is supposed to act on.

I think I'm pretty close.

This blocks the whole thing:

`sudo systemd-run --pty --pipe --uid=1000 --property=ProtectHome=read-only /bin/bash`

This is almost what I want but since / is still rw, the rest of the home folder stays rw:

`sudo systemd-run --pty --pipe --uid=1000 --property=ReadWritePaths=$(pwd) /bin/bash`

Can I have both at the same time i.e. home read-only but with a single path inside home rw?

Comment: Hi Francois, welcome to unix & linux stack exchange. If you change `/` to read only, you will run into trouble; logs won't be able to run and vital system services will crash to say the least. 

I think what you're looking for is something along the lines of `chroot` to only allow the user access to write to their home directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, you can combine those two directives. But I’m a bit confused by your question: you say that you want to make *everything* read-only instead of the user’s home directory, but also that `ProtectHome=read-only` “blocks the whole thing”? But `ProtectHome=read-only` has no effect on `/`, only on `/home` and `/root`.

I think this should do what you want:

```
sudo systemd-run --pty --pipe --uid=1000 -p ReadOnlyPaths=/ -p ReadWritePaths="$(pwd)"
```

If you only want the other home directories to be read-only, not the entire file system, use `ProtectHome=read-only` instead of `ReadOnlyPaths=/`.

Comment: That works perfectly

Comment: Be aware that these do not provide a security boundary. For a long-running script, see https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/9857  And if your home directory is on NFS and you mount FUSE filesystems like sshfs underneath it, the FUSE mounts will not be protected (but this only applies to the current code in Git - the systemd releases before now e.g. v238 will simply fail to start the service if there is any such mount, which was considered even worse behaviour  https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/9844).

Comment: Ideally you would want either an implementation using kernel APIs which have only been planned https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20180602040434.GW30522@ZenIV.linux.org.uk/ , or put the script in a container along with all its requirements, something like Docker, and then only bind-mount the specific directory into the container.